# Facebook permissions dialog displaying in different languages

Tags: ruby, facebook, facebook-graph-api, permissions, omniauth

I'm working on an app that makes heavy use of facebook's graph API. I'm requesting the following permissions:

- my_photos
- friends_photos
- my_relationships
- relationship_details
- hometown

I'm using the omniauth ruby gem to specify these permissions and acquire an access token.

I'm getting reports of the application authorization dialog displaying in seemingly random languages.

Has anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 0):

It's really hard to say when facebook API doesn't have a bug! Yeah! I really mean it.
It's not supposed to happen. The language is supposed to be shown according to user locale.
So, I think you should just wait, or you can add a bug in Facebook Developers websites' bug tracker

Answer (score 0):

A bug has already been reported on Facebook

See [How to change language in Facebook login page or dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10477975/how-to-change-language-in-facebook-login-page-or-dialog)

And http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/407246299295529?browse=search_4fa410ea79db26337556383