# How to change language in Facebook login page or dialog?

Tags: iphone, facebook, localization

I have a problem for a long time, I don't figure out where the problem is.
My own app and this Hackbook Demo app have the same situation when auth dialog popup. 
No matter web dialog or Faccbook native app, I'd like it to show in English. Even, my ios language is English, the auth dialog is still not in English.

somebody help me, please, thanks!

[image]

Comment: it depends on the ip source where you visit  , not depend ont your ios system language

Comment: would love to get answer on this. i did search on this but the road last year

Comment: @adali, but other app in my iPhone can show in English UI. how come?

Comment: other app use facebook dialog?

Comment: @adali, you're right, it seem like a bug and appear recently. and What's work around? Do you know, adali, thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Its a Facebook-level issue. check this :

http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/407246299295529?browse=search_4fa410ea79db26337556383

the problem is :

> "On initial login using Facebook, the dialog asking the user to
>   authorize this application is displayed in seemingly random
>   languages.. Only Happens when user is connected over Wifi."

Comment: thanks, @Malek! And I'm wonder this issue was not found before. Perhaps it's just coming...?