# Can I set the language of the SSO Facebook screen?

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, ipad, facebook-graph-api

My device is in english or spanish but the language of the SSO authorization screen of Facebook, in app or from Safari, is always in another language (maybe in polish? I don't know :).

Is it possible to set the language or this is a Facebook problem?

Comment: check my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10477975/705559)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a Facebook issue, the question is a duplicated of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10477975/how-to-change-language-in-facebook-login-page-or-dialog). By the way, the answer is here:

http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/407246299295529?browse=search_4fa410ea79db26337556383

> On initial login using Facebook, the dialog asking the user to
>   authorize this application is displayed in seemingly random
>   languages.. Only Happens when user is connected over Wifi.