# Facebook permissions language

Tags: facebook, permissions

I made a facebook app in french, but when the permission dialog appears, it's in english, even if the user is french from France.

I'm calling the permission dialog from the facebook as3 api.

How can i turn the permission dialog in french.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You saw this one?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10477975/how-to-change-language-in-facebook-login-page-or-dialog

Comment: I saw it... But what is the solution ?
My app is only in french and permission dialog is always in english...

Comment: How does calling the Auth dialog via AS3 acutally work?

Answer (score 0):

One guy said. "On initial login using Facebook, the dialog asking the user to authorize this application is displayed in seemingly random languages.. Only Happens when user is connected over Wifi."

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered that when I go to my app directly on my website, the dialog is in french, but when i go to it with : apps.facebook.com/mynamespace or with an onglet page, the dialog is in english... Can't understand why ?